# Ajax отправка запроса и ответ

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Всем ку подскажите имееться php регистрациия вот она

```
<?php
include_once ("db.php");
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
session_start();

$reg_email = "/^[\.a-z0-9_-]{3,20}@[\.a-z0-9_-]{1,20}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i";
$reg_pass = "/^[\.\+\*a-z0-9_-]{6,30}$/i";

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    if (//проверка введенных данных
            preg_match($reg_email, $_POST['email']) && preg_match($reg_pass, $_POST['pass'])
    ) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = md5(sha1($_POST['pass'] . "key"));

        $sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql_res) != 0) {
            //выдаем ошибку, если пользователь уже существует
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Email занят";
            header("location: index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET email='$email', pass='$pass'")) {
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Пользователь успешно создан!";

                $tmp_id = mysql_insert_id(); //id только что зарегистрированного учатника
                $sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT email,pass FROM users WHERE id=$tmp_id"); //сразу же выполняем вход нового пользователя
                $arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
                $_SESSION['user'] = $arr['email'];
                //меняем строку авторизации/регистрации на строку приветствия авторизованного пользователя
                $_SESSION['auth'] = "<a href='#' id='email'><b>" . $_SESSION['user'] . "</b></a> | <a href='#'>Личный кабинет</a> | <a href='?stop=true'>Выход</a>";
                header("location: index.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

А вот js

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
        var msg = $('#regform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'r/reg.php',
            data: msg,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.results').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Подскажите как получить ответ от сервера отправка идет успешно а вот получить не могу и данные в БД приходят если все правильно ввел. Зарание всем спасибо.

Comment: # @lodem009, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

А что вы собираетесь принимать, если сервер не только не возвращает никаких данных, но еще и вместо обычного успешного выполнения "202 OK" выдает редирект, по умолчанию "302 Found"? Ошибки при этом не возникает, но и никакого ответа в success вы не дождетесь.

```
$.ajax({

  ............

  statusCode: {
    302: function() {
      alert( "redirect" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Status Code:200 OK 
по умолчанию ничего не выдаёт, а что нужно сделать чтобы сервер возратил данные???

Comment: да 302 OK выдает

Answer (score 0):

1. $_SESSION используешь не по назначению.
2. нет echo, нет передачи нормального response
3. Json (опкод твоего контроллера + данные) отдавай в js controller клиента в качестве ответа со стороны php контроллера на сервере, получится нормальный ajax. 
   Посмотри примеры:
   https://github.com/ArtNazarov/LazyJs , https://github.com/ArtNazarov/lazyjs/blob/master/lazy.js

Comment: спасибо сейчас попробую если что то непонятно будут сюда отпешусь.

Comment: artnazarov а вы мне не поможете что то я разобраться не могу а тоя в js полный нуль???

Comment: пару минут, пример напишу

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы пассивные данные возвращать (разметку) и каждый раз обновлять целиком страницу мы переходим на обмен опкодами и данными между клиентом и сервером и точечное обновление интерфейса. 
Подробнее: http://artnazarov.postach.io/298390-hashcode

Comment: спасибо сейчас напишу попробую)) посмотрим что получиться